# Fixed div in non-visible area of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a grid control that's not shown completely on the page and on the bottom of the page i have a horizontal scrollbar so you can see all the grid columns. Next to the grid in the non-visible area i have grid controls that must remain fixed in case the grid height becomes too big so the users can access them any time while on that page.

This is roughly the situation i have at the moment:

[image]

I need the controls to remain on the most right part of the page and not on the most right of the viewport. Is this possible or is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT:

```
<div style="display:flex;width:700px">
      <div style="height:1000px;width:1000px;background:red"></div>
      <div style="height:150px;width:300px;background:yellow;"></div>
    </div>
```

The yellow square need to follow you while you scroll vertically and needs to be shown only if you scroll horizontally to the end of the red square.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand whjat you want, you need to use `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed`

Comment: What's the problem with the controls, isn't it already at the most right side of the page?

Comment: does adding "right:0" in the css not attach it to the right side of the view port? also, overflow hidden on the container would get rid of the scroll bar but that probably isn't what you want.  Some code would be useful.

Comment: @MrLister i don;t need position absolute because i need the controls to follow me if the grid has a bigger height.

Answer (score 0):

First, Ensure that your container element has positioning declared, i.e. relative, fixed, absolute, et al.  Then use `position: absolute;` for your controls.

Set your right and top offsets for proper positioning, and give your grid div enough `margin-right: ;` to keep it (grid div) from coinciding with your controls.

**[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/fadujokori/edit?html,css,output)**

Is this what you're aiming for?

Comment: The grid can have a big height and there would be a vertical scrollbar on the page so the controls must follow me while scrolling the grid and also to remain next to the grid from the right side.